# Nodal analysis with ideal operational amplifier

Tags: circuit-analysis

I want to do a nodal analysis on this circuit

[image: Circuit]

Before I do the nodal analysis I want to construct an equivalent circuit, such that the analysis is easier. My question is if the my constructed circuit is equivalent to the original one and if it is possible to make a even easier looking construction?

[image: 1st try]

Comment: Analysis often becomes easier if you look at the **functions** certain circuit perform. Look at the opamp, R3 and the (K-1)R3 resistor. What **function** does this circuit perform? Then replace those components with a representation of that function. Hint: I'd use a ...-controlled .... source.

Comment: Also your schematic does not show the output of the opamp so it cannot be correct.

Comment: Thanks for the response :) Since the amp is ideal I was thinking the incoming current is 0 since the voltage is 0 between + and - in the amp.

Comment: Indeed that is true and the voltage between + and - input will also be zero. You **can** solve all that including the opamp and feedback but the net result will be that it is a voltage amplifier. If you need to prove it, just solve the opamp and feedback separately. The fact that C1 also connects to the opamp does not matter as it is on the output which is a voltage source so C1 cannot influence the opamp's feedback through R3.

Comment: Hmm I kind of can't wrap my head around this. Could you maybe provide an example or solution to this specific problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proposed equivalent circuit is not equivalent because it does not provide any mechanism to force \$v_+ = v_-\$ and it doesn't provide any mechanism to inject current at \$v_o\$.

If you want solve an op-amp circuit by nodal analysis, you can replace the op-amp with a very high-gain amplifier or VCVS.

For pen and paper analysis it's usually simpler to not strictly use nodal analysis but use the negative feedback equations (\$v_+=v_-\$, \$i_+=0\$, and \$i_- = 0\$) instead (after you've confirmed that negative feedback is correctly established).

Comment: Could you maybe show me how that would look like in this example?